# Focus control issue in a SearchView as part of a fragment

Tags: android, search, view, focus, google-tv

I have a SeachView inside of a Fragment in an Android 3.1 application currently running on an emulator destined eventually for GoogleTV (which places some limitations on what the app can and cannot do).   When I move the pointer over the query icon in the SearchView and  click, a flashing cursor is displayed in the query box.  When I go to type in a search term, focus shifts to the next fragment.  However, if after I click on the search icon, I press the tab key, the cursor remains in the query box and typed text shows up in the query box, as expected. I have attempted to pull the embedded TextView from the SearchView and have it request focus to no avail. I also tried to force fire a keypressed event on the tab key.  No dice.  Any suggestions on what to look at for keeping control of the focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SearchView should get focus when you click the search icon itself. If the focus is in Searchview,the 'X' button should take focus if you dpad right or press tab key.That's the default behavior.